# Link custom URL with actual url without .htaccess

Tags: php, url, redirect

I have a requirement in which I need to create custom urls which are linked to actual URL. For example if actuall URL is **www.google.com** then this URL will be display as **www.exampleurls.com/something/whater**. ANd When I click on this URL it will be redirect to **www.google.com**. This URLs also should independently so  and href is not useful.

I can not configure .htaccess because of accessibility. :( is it possible only by database and php ?

for example: tinyurls, but I don't want tiny url.

Comment: Try to `encode` or `decode` url

Comment: Assuming you have many of these urls, you can store in your DB the new url and the original url, and do a lookup each time for the new url, and render a redirect header in your server logic to the original url. If you only have a few of them, then you can hard code them in a single PHP script. Both ways make use of the 404 error handler page on your site.

Comment: Could I understand that your domain is **exampleurls.com** ?

Answer (score 0):

1- Option;

Encode URL with any encoding method i.e `base64`, `base_convert` and keep them in database in a field that fixed by your hash i.e `CHAR(8)`.

```
function foo($url) {
    // yields 7-8 chars, sprintf will fix it to 8 chars padding 0 to the left
    return sprintf("%'08s", base_convert(crc32($url), 16, 36));
    // or use md5 that more reliable for collision issue
    // yields 24-25 chars, sprintf will fix it to 25 chars padding 0 to the left
    // return sprintf("%'025s", base_convert(md5($url), 16, 36));
}

<a href="/redirect/0a5sz8yf">Go to Google!</a>

// redirect file
result = get_url_from_db(hash);
if (result.url == null) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
} else {
    header('Location: '. result.url, true, 301);
}
```

2- Option;

Use a proper URL shortener, keep the short hashes in database and so on.